# Changing your mind about changing your vote

Tags: discussion, voting, change-vote

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undoing an old vote cannot be recast because vote is too old](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21462/undoing-an-old-vote-cannot-be-recast-because-vote-is-too-old)

If somebody edits their question, you can change your vote. But if you change your mind about changing the vote, you receive the message "Vote too old to be changed".

Shouldn't you have a brief window in which to restore the vote?

Comment: Looks like my question is a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21462/undoing-an-old-vote-cannot-be-recast-because-vote-is-too-old

Comment: You should be allowed to change your vote whenever you change your mind.  There should be no time limit at all.