# Cancel a vote so that the tally goes back to zero and not minus

Tags: support, voting, undo

If I vote up a post, the vote score will increase from 0 to 1. But then I might change my mind or repent  my actions and wish to take back that vote.

If I vote it down, the score will be minus instead of zero.

How do I undo my vote so that the score will come back down to zero instead of showing the minus 1?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Click the vote again to undo. This will take you back to what it was before you voted.

However, [there is a time limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21462/undoing-an-old-vote-cannot-be-recast-because-vote-is-too-old) if you don't do it quick enough.

Comment: how? I tried with this ans. When I arrived it has 4 votes. I vote up and changed to 5. I quickly vote down and changed to 3 (as if I were votting down originally). What I want is left it in 4.

Comment: To undo your vote, click the same vote button again. In other words, if you upvoted and didn't mean to, click the upvote button a second time. If you downvoted and didn't mean to, click the downvote button a second time.