# Why is it impossible to undo votes?

Tags: support, voting, undo

Today I voted up the wrong answer. I noticed that there's no way to undo your votes. When you have voted an answer you are forced to vote it, even if you don't want to. I immediately noticed the error and I could just change my vote to up or down, not delete my vote. It makes no sense at all, imho.
Since you are able to change your vote within 5 minutes, you should also be able to remove your vote entirely.
I can't believe no one noticed that before...

Comment: Actually, you can. For a bad upvote, just click "upvote" again.

Comment: Sorry to everyone for this non-sense question.

Comment: It's cool. It was useful, to be honest; it made me realize that the [voting FAQ page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/are-there-any-voting-limits) doesn't include this information. Working on fixing that now....

Comment: @Thomas Don't worry about it, just accept an answer once you can (you don't need to edit the question to include the answer)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30557/cancel-a-vote-so-that-the-tally-goes-back-to-zero-and-not-minus (not actually voting to close only because I'm out of votes for the day)

Comment: Now also a dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/are-there-any-voting-limits, the newly updated FAQ page on voting

Comment: That's not fair! :P

Comment: @PopularDemand: the FAQ doesn't have this info, but the tooltip does, and did, so...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- Click on the upvote icon (the up arrow) to upvote.

  > [image]
- Click again to undo your upvote.

  > [image]
- Click on the number to display the upvote and downvote counts, instead of just the total score. (Note that you must be an [established user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) to do this.)

  > [image]
  >
  > [image]

Comment: That so many people aren't aware of this suggests that it needs a UI improvement.

Answer (score 8):

You can cancel it: click on the vote you've cast again, i.e. click on the up arrow again to cancel an upvote.

As you've noticed with up / down you can only do this for five minutes. I did exactly the same as you and ended up downvoting to cancel at first. At least I got the critic badge out of it :-)

Comment: Omg, sorry, i didn't noticed that. I feel so stupid.

Comment: I have been trying to figure this out for so long. When I hover over the arrow it says (click again to undo) but that just locks in my vote. It doesn't say anything about "within the first 5 minutes". Maybe after 5 minutes, those notes should change and say "THIS WILL LOCK IN YOUR VOTE!"