# Remove upvote on question

Tags: support, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cancel a vote so that the tally goes back to zero and not minus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30557/cancel-a-vote-so-that-the-tally-goes-back-to-zero-and-not-minus)

Accidentaly I just upvoted a question that wasn't particular good in the first place. When I tried to remove my upvote, it was replaced by a vote down. Why isn't there an option to just remove the up/down vote.

Comment: Hm? All you need to do is click on the upvote arrow again, did you click the downvote arrow to remove your upvote?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at your question's upvote arrow. The tool tips says: ***click again to undo***

> [image]

> This question shows research errort; it is useful and clear ***(click again to undo)***

Comment: I love the screenshot having "asked 32 secs ago". You do move fast!

Comment: @hims056 It's not a *problem* if you got it right the first time (no edits as of yet, I see)! ;-)

Comment: How do we get them to fix the design of this interface so that clicking in the middle removes any up or down votes?