# How to undo a vote UP or vote DOWN?

Tags: support, voting, undo

In the past and recently I have clicked accidentally on the UP arrow to vote up but this is only an accident.

If I click on DOWN arrow to redo my vote, the counter is directly decremented by 1.

I search, I searched and I don't find any solution to remove my accidental vote.

Example:

The vote counter for a specific question is 0.

I click accidentally on UP and the vote counter is 1.

I see that immediately and I will correct my error and I click on the DOWN arrow but now the counter is -1 and not 0.

What is the solution to my problem?

Comment: is clicking again on your respective vote to undo it not working?

Comment: *To simply undo a vote; i.e. make it as if you had never voted in the first place; [click the "lit up" vote button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30557/cancel-a-vote-so-that-the-tally-goes-back-to-zero-and-not-minus). The result will be that neither an upvote nor a downvote is active, and you can come back to vote [any time you like](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18360/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-but-i-havent-voted/18373#18373). Only cast votes are locked in.*

Comment: @Abhishek: thanks, but I never try before to click a second time on same button to undo effect. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Click the button you used to vote *again*, and the vote will revert.

It even says so on the tooltip:

[image]

This is a valuable lesson for using Stack Exchange: pay attention to the tooltips/hovers. E.g. try hovering over a time indicator like 'asked 29 mins ago'.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But why [duplicate] has been added to the question's title. I understand that the answer is duplicate but not the question. My question is more direct than 'What are the limits on how I can cast, change, and retract votes?'

Comment: [*The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: @schlebe On Meta Stack Exchange, duplicates are also used to direct users to FAQs that answer their question.

Answer (score 1):

Click vote up button again, then your upvote will be undone, but only can do that inside 5 minutes after the vote.

Answer (score 0):

To undo a vote, you have to click the same button again.

For instance, to undo an upvote, you need to click the Up arrow again.

Comment: I don't undertand why others have voted your question DOWN since they don't have posted any reason. So I vote UP :-)

Comment: I'd also like to know why only I was downvoted.