# Got "your vote is too old" when I don't have a vote

Tags: support, voting, locked-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undoing an old vote cannot be recast because vote is too old](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21462/undoing-an-old-vote-cannot-be-recast-because-vote-is-too-old)

On this question: [Hamcrest's lessThan doesn't compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821245/hamcrests-lessthan-doesnt-compile), tried to vote an answer and got the said error, even though I don't have any vote on that answer.

I did vote once, but undid it quickly after.

Comment: Even though you undid the vote, you still voted, and this counts towards the lock. Therefore you can't vote again until the post is edited.

Comment: That's not nice. Is there a reasoning behind this? If I accidentally vote and immediately unvote, this should count for all intents and purposes as if I never voted.

Comment: I just saw this was closed as duplicate. Duplicate of which question?

Comment: @ripper: The duplicate is always quoted at the top of the closed question, with a link.