# Can't upvote an answer (says the vote is too old)

Tags: support, voting, locked-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undoing an old vote cannot be recast because vote is too old](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21462/undoing-an-old-vote-cannot-be-recast-because-vote-is-too-old)

I got an answer to a question that had me very very stuck.  (This is it: [WPF - Change a style in code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971149/wpf-change-a-style-in-code-behind))

I upvoted because I was happy that I got an answer.  But then I said to myself, "you should just check to see if this answer even works before you upvote."  So I undid the upvote and went and checked the answer.

Turns out the answer was fabulous, I wish I could up vote it several times.  I was surprised when I tried to re-cast my upvote and was told that my vote was too old to be changed!

I had not even voted!  I had un-voted?  Does this message mean that my un-vote is too old be changed?  If so that is sad.  I got a great answer that deserves to be rewarded.

Comment: There, I edited the answer so the vote timer is reset. Knock yourself out.