# Touch an Answer Request

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation, help

Can someone with lots of Stack Overflow rep go make a trivial edit to the accepted answer to this question so I can vote it up?

[WPF Animation - Why Can't "By" have a negitive value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903945/wpf-animation-why-cant-by-have-a-negitive-value)

If you are curious, you can see why I cannot vote it up now in this question:

[Can't upvote an answer (says the vote is too old)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34009/cant-upvote-an-answer-says-the-vote-is-too-old-closed)

This has happened again (and probably will many times) with the above question.  If someone with lots of Stack Overflow rep is feeling benevolent I would appreciate the help (as would the answerer I am sure).

Comment: You should be more careful when voting.

Comment: Ask the post owner to edit his post. Much easier than messing up Meta.

Comment: what happens if you unaccept his post, upvote it, then re-accept?

Comment: @Roboto: It still blocks me.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a reminder, you accepted his answer and that did give him 15 rep points.

If you did exactly what the meta questions you linked to, unfortunantly that is by design and not currently considered a bug by Jeff and his team. The vote restriction timer is started whenever you vote and continues even if you undo a vote. I know, it is annoying.

Comment: I know.  But I wanted to up vote the answer too.