# Can't upvote an answer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undoing an old vote cannot be recast because vote is too old](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21462/undoing-an-old-vote-cannot-be-recast-because-vote-is-too-old)

This happens here: [How to run only the latest/a given test using Rspec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401970/how-to-run-only-the-latest-a-given-test-using-rspec)

No upvote/downvote is marked:

[image]

And if I try to upvote it :

[image]

Comment: I wonder how many times this will be reported before Jeff decides it's worth fixing? It must have been reported at least 50 times by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means you had voted for the answer, and then changed your mind and cleared your vote while still in the grace period where changes were allowed.