# Upvote Removal, can't put back

Tags: bug, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undoing an old vote cannot be recast because vote is too old](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21462/undoing-an-old-vote-cannot-be-recast-because-vote-is-too-old)

I gave a good post an upvote earlier this morning.  I then accidentally clicked the up vote button again canceling out the upvote.  When I then went to click it to put it back I can't because it says the vote is too old to be changed.

Answer in question is Vatine's answer to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/130665/cisco-qos-guidance) of mine.

Comment: See - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21462/undoing-an-old-vote-cannot-be-recast-because-vote-is-too-old

Comment: ChrisF: Ah I see, I added another upvote as I agree that by-design doesn't make sense to me.