# Sometimes I can't visually see that I've voted on a question

Tags: bug, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I can't vote on an answer issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61429/i-cant-vote-on-an-answer-issue)

An [example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7466/) of a question I voted on, but can't see the uptick highlighted in orange. Attempting to vote on it, I get *You last voted on this answer...*. I've seen this behavior on a few occasions.

Answer (score 2):

You probably voted for it and then retracted it (perhaps accidentally). That means your vote is now locked in as nothing.

If the answer is edited, you should be able to change your vote.

Comment: I thought if I retract a vote, the DB behaves as if I never voted.

Comment: @Tshepang: No, and in fact there have been a number of bugs filed on Meta on this subject -- all marked 'status-bydesign'. Just looking down the related list on the right, I see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61429/i-cant-vote-on-an-answer-issue), [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46064/upvote-removal-cant-put-back), [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72865/why-cant-i-re-vote-after-having-unvoted), [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18360/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-but-i-havent-voted)... and that's all I can fit here.

Comment: Oh, then this a dupe then. I voted to close it.

Comment: @Tshepang: Fair enough. Can you make an updated screenshot for that question and propose an edit?