# Change a vote from downvote to upvote via editing

Tags: support, voting

I downvoted an answer, being convinced it was mistaken. I then went to check it, just in case, and turned out I was the mistaken, but the window had already passed. So, having the privileges I have, I trivially edited the question to be able to undo the downvote.

That all worked. But then I wanted to upvote the question as well, and the system wouldn't let me, showing the "cannot modify the vote unless it is edited" popup, even when the question had been edited.

Do I need to wait 5 minutes, and do another edit to be able to upvote? Is this by design?

I think that I should be able to change from downvote to upvote directly, without having to wait for two edits (maybe my mistake was to change it from downvote to novote instead of directly to upvote.)

EDIT: Confirmed. If I make a second edit 5 minutes afterward I can actually upvote the answer. What I haven't tested is if I can directly change the vote from downvote to upvote without having this to happen.

EDIT 2: I know the proper course of action would have been to do the check before downvoting. But I'm human and err sometimes.

EDIT 3: This is a dupe. It is here [Vote Reversal Time Limit Concerns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18788/vote-reversal-time-limit-concerns) and the problem is indeed changing from down to no to up instead of directly from down to up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the system's count and check, you threw in [way too many votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18788/vote-reversal-time-limit-concerns/18827#18827).

> Be aware that if you want to change your vote there are two different ways:
>
> - cast initial upvote
> - click upvote again to "undo" upvote
> - click downvote
>
> That's 3 votes by our reckoning.
>
> - cast initial upvote
> - click downvote to convert your upvote to a downvote
>
> That's 2 votes by our reckoning.
>
> Don't be surprised if a) is blocked, while b) is not.
>
> And of course you can always re-vote after an edit, but if you are sloppy in the way you cast your votes (see above), you may be blocked regardless.

So by you undoing the vote, that was still counted as a vote action. And happening after the edit, you had one shot. If you had clicked the upvote right after the instead, that would have been still just the one vote action.

Comment: Yes, had found that already, see EDIT 3, you rep-ho :)

Comment: Those robots did not show up!

Answer (score 1):

It occurred to me the other day that telling me that my "vote cannot be changed unless the question is edited" is a waste of time, since I have enough rep to simply edit the question myself and then change the vote.

Why make me do that? If I have enough rep to edit the question the system should just let me change the vote...

Comment: Thing is that editing leaves a trail. And everyone will know it was you who changed the vote.