# How can someone remove an upvote from an answer that was posted a long time ago, and hasn't been edited?

Tags: support, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How long can you change your vote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133294/how-long-can-you-change-your-vote)

Re: [Problem with swfobject_api or jwplayer module in Drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10515/problem-with-swfobject-api-or-jwplayer-module-in-drupal/10545#10545)

I just received an 'unupvote' for the above answer. My understanding (from experience) is that  once you have upvoted, you cannot remove said upvote after a certain amount of time has passed, unless the post has been edited.

The answer was posted in September last year, and hasn't been edited.

Who (apart from devs) has the power to do this? Or is this something available to everyone and I've just not worked out how to do it yet?

Comment: Thanks @Danielδ, I did search but didn't find that one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One really *fancy* way to do this is to edit the post, remove your upvote, and then manually revert your edit (which destroys the revision, so there's no evidence of the edit).

*Note: This method is only available to people with edit privileges and will likely [not be around for long](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133301/undone-edits-disappear-from-revision-history).*

Interesting point: [The timeline for that post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/10515/timeline) doesn't show that the answer was ever upvoted, so apparently that is stricken from history as well.

Comment: Also see [Change a vote from downvote to upvote via editing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23147/change-a-vote-from-downvote-to-upvote-via-editing)

Comment: @Danielδ Thanks, I didn't realize the edit-to-change-vote logic was that touchy.

Comment: That makes sense, many thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you have not edited the post after it was voted, then removing a vote can be done using the following steps:

- Edit the post, for example adding text
- Remove the vote
- Edit the post, removing the text you added

If the edits are done during the grace period, there will not be any track left from them. It doesn't actually require any specific privilege, if not the privilege of editing every post.

That is what I have read in a post on this very site. I don't remember exactly which question asked about this.

Comment: @jadarnel's answer has the link for this; http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133301/undone-edits-disappear-from-revision-history

Comment: It was the question Daniel δ suggests as duplicate.

Comment: Ahh....sneaky! Cheers for the clarification