# My vote is now locked in?

Tags: discussion, usability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Idea behind “Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75477/idea-behind-your-vote-is-now-locked-in-unless-this-answer-is-edited)

I fail to see the reasoning behind not allowing me to change my mind on an answer.

Here's my situation: I read the answer, saw that it was suggesting something that I considered not ideal and so downvoted the answer. After further research I realized what I had originally considered the ideal solution was in fact not possible, thus I decided to remove my downvote on the question.

To my surprise, Stack Overflow in all its supreme-overlordliness wouldn't let me undo my downvote, presumably because my chance to change my mind had expired!

Comment: Consider for a moment the possibility that there might be reasons why this feature was introduced. Apart from a desire for supreme-overlordliness.

Comment: @Pekka The word "feature" should be used very loosely here. The more I think about it, the more I think it's a stupid restriction.