# How to change locked votes when facts have changed?

Tags: support

I'm receiving the following error when trying to change a vote for an answer that used to be correct, but due to the passage of time is no longer correct:

```
You last voted on this answer
Mar 11 '12 at 18:47
Your vote is now locked in
unless this answer is edited
```

What is the proper way to change a vote for an answer that was correct and has now become incorrect?

Comment: Note: I've read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75477/idea-behind-your-vote-is-now-locked-in-unless-this-answer-is-edited

Answer (score 1):

You simply can't.

Instead perhaps leave a comment alerting that the answer is no longer correct. After all, that might be more productive than a suddenly changed vote without a real explanation. The author of the answer has a chance to address your concern, and if he doesn't, there is at least a comment indicating that the answer might no longer be correct.