# Why is there no more a chance to change your vote at least once? Or at least just remove it?

Tags: discussion, answers, voting

It happens pretty often that I upvote an answer, then find out it was wrong. In the past, it was possible to change your vote once, at least I think so. Currently, you guys are giving me two options:

- Do not vote until I test the answer, which means I'll forget to upvote 50% (or more) good answers that helped me
- Edit something just to be able to change that vote (but that would be nasty), when I find out answer actually sucks
- Upvote all other answers to make it up when I find out the answer I upvoted sucks

And guys, many answers that were voted to heaven actually suck. Often there's almost as upvoted comment saying "*I have a XY problem with this answer, can you explain?*". But the upvotes keep coming nevertheless.

Comment: So you want be able to upvote something when you've no idea whether it's any good and then be able to downvote it later when you figure out it isn't. That wastes everybody else's time looking at an answer that's no good while it has the upvote. Why not just use the favourites mechanism to keep track of things you might want to upvote?

Comment: Why are you upvoting answers that you don't know are correct in the first place?

Comment: Are there some users without hostile attitude on meta SE? Yeah, just as others do, I upvote answer after reading it.

Comment: If you find someone you like you could alternatively just bookmark it or favourite the question. Then you can revisit it whenever you wish and when you have the time to properly evaluate the content.

Comment: This was the case from day 1, it has never changed. You probably used to undo the vote quickly in the past, in the 5 minutes window. Anyway, The answer by Tim Post makes perfect sense to me, and if you have a different opinion, you can add new answer in there.

Comment: @Bart I sure can, or I can keep the tab open. But technically, I usually only recall about that answer if it *doesn't* work, otherwise I just keep coding. And my question really was about **why** is it no longer possible to undownvote and unupvote. We all make mistakes, right?

Comment: Also: [Idea behind “Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75477/262755)

Comment: The reason for this is contained here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6460/if-you-just-witnessed-tactical-downvoting-is-it-a-reportable-offense/18046#18046 ***Tactical Downvoting*** used to be a method where you would answer the question, downvote all the other answers, which would cause your answer to rise up.  You would then come back later and remove your downvote to avoid the negative effects of downvoting, or being caught using this method.  All voting is now locked in because the same abuses in reverse can happen with upvoting, and to provide consistent user experience.

Comment: That being said, the tooltip when you hover over the upvote button is *"This answer is useful"*.  By upvoting you aren't signifying correctness, so don't feel like you need to retract it.  It made you consider and try one possible course of action, and you probably learned from that, so it is still useful.  If you really only want to upvote things that meet your other standards, such as correctness, the answer isn't to change the system, but to change how you are using it.  I'm afraid your best option is to wait until you've verified it meets your standards before voting.