# Bug: Vote to old to be changed, but no vote present

Tags: bug, voting, time-limit

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Bug with ‘Vote too old to be changed’](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19527/bug-with-vote-too-old-to-be-changed)
>   [Vote Reversal Time Limit Concerns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18788/vote-reversal-time-limit-concerns)

This was already [reported by Click Upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19527/bug-with-vote-too-old-to-be-changed-closed), but wrongly closed as a duplicate.  I found Click Upvote's when I went to report it myself and decided to raise it again when I saw his question had been closed.

If you vote on an answer but right away you retract your vote by clicking the up/downvote icon again, so the image turns back to gray from orange, it should mean that you have no vote on that answer.

However if you later try to go back and upvote/downvote that answer, it says 'Vote too old to be changed', **despite the fact that you have at this point no vote cast on the answer**.

Note, I have this state for two answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731295/need-to-convert-this-for-loop-to-a-while-loop/2731440#2731440).

Comment: Ironically, even though said question might've been wrongly closed as a duplicate, this would be correctly called a duplicate of said question.

Comment: Jeff's answer to this question - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18788/vote-reversal-time-limit-concerns - explains the situation.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21462/undoing-an-old-vote-cannot-be-recast-because-vote-is-too-old/ OP that linked one talks about immediately redoing the vote, this one tries to redo sometime "later". The error (and probably mechanism) is the same though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you vote on a post, you have a small window to "change" the vote. It's not a window to remove or reverse the vote. Changing your vote to "no vote" is no different than reversing your vote. This is why, for example, if you do vote down and then immediately retract it, you can get the "Critic" badge without ever having a downvote on your record.

What this basically introduces is that you should only vote when you truly understand your stance on the post. If you think "I might want to vote this up now, but I'm not sure, but maybe I'll vote it up later even though the content hasn't changed at all", don't vote. Wait until you can be certain that you do want to cast that vote. If you're indecisive to the point that you "wasted" your vote on a no-vote, then you shouldn't have voted in the first place. This is really no different than voting a post up or down, then thinking a few days later "Maybe I shouldn't have", and retracting it.

Another way to look at it... you had voted up, then you decided "This post doesn't deserve my vote". That was your decision in retracting your vote.

Comment: No amount of deliberation helps when your mouse slips and you click someplace you didn't mean to.