# Ask moderators to undo my votes or make them upvotes

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes, up-votes

I have downvoted some answers or questions in Stack Overflow that now that I see, my choice was not right and I should either make them neutral or upvote.

I read in another Meta Q&A regarding this issue that I only have 5 minutes to revert it or the Q&A gets edited.

I ask the moderators to provide me a way to undo some of votes, so that I can change them. Should I list them here? Else, what should I do?

Comment: You can change your votes after an edit.

Comment: Can those posts be improved in any way? If so, you can suggest an edit. Then, if it's approved, you can undo/reverse your vote and you get 2 rep points as a bonus (for the approved edit). Note: do _**not**_ make superficial edits just so you can undo your vote. They will most likely be rejected, which might affect your ability to edit other posts. Only edit if you think you can improve the post.

Comment: On another note: In general, if you're seeking help from SO moderators, you should post on Meta.SO, not Meta.SE. That said, moderators cannot help you in this particular case.

Comment: Related (hints at "tactical voting" as the reason for the rule): *[Vote reversal time limit concerns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18788)*. Is there a better meta question for answering the "why"?

Comment: Mods can't undo or change someone's votes. They can't even see who votes what.

Answer (score 8):

> I ask the moderators to provide me a way to undo some of votes, so that I can change them. Should I list them here? Else, what should I do?

Moderators can't undo votes either, nor provide you with a way to do so. Like people said in the comments, and like you seem to have discovered too, if you can edit the posts to improve them, do so, and you can correct your vote afterwards. Perhaps some have already been edited since you voted on them?

Listing the posts here won't help. You only have 81 downvotes for all time on your Stack Overflow profile, and if only some of those were 'wrong', I would say it's not a huge problem.

What you should do is try and see what you can fix by editing posts, and be more careful with your votes from now on.

<sub>Technically, you could flag your posts for moderator attention and request them to escalate this to the community management team, but I doubt people would be happy if everyone started doing that for every vote they'd later want to reverse. I'm willing to bet such a flag would be declined by the moderators. So I'm going to recommend against doing that, and instead say you just have to live with the consequences of your actions and learn your lesson.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, I read all the comments. By my question, suppose I downvoted your answer for thing like `return my_var` in Python. Suppose last year I did this for you and I thought it was not correct, but now after a year I gained more knowledge and I found your answer was right. Then if you think the past's function cannot be changed, then I will be more aware from now on. But I'm not happy of what I did to some people:( That's my mistake

Comment: Unless the answer is edited, with a productive and valid edit, you won’t be able to change your vote.

Comment: @Saeed I will know my answer is correct, and probably just think one of two things: a.) Someone is downvoting moderators or b.) [Someone lost their keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288240/369802). In the grand scheme of things, a single downvote is annoying like a mosquito buzzing near your ear when you're trying to sleep, but not much more than that. It won't kill me.

Comment: @Sky No, 100% no. Moderators can't undo up/down/accept votes and even CMs can't. Within SE employees only those with access to the production database can invalidate votes for cases of voting fraud. That is maybe a handful of SE staff, certainly not all SE employee. And correcting a single vote is **not** a fraud case so bothering a SE staff with it is out of the question.